# android intents from reflection

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I have a question that should have a really simple answer I can't find.

I'd like to start an activity (that is already registered in the manifest file

The activity should start from another activity basing on the choice of a list:

```
String testName = list[pos];
try
{
  Class testClass = Class.forName("com.test.design." + testName);
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, testClass);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

the AVD gives "The application has stopped unexpectedly"..

Isn't the right way to start an intent?

Ok: The LOG gives me: "unable to find activity". Are you sure you declare activity in the manifest file?.
In the manifest file between the application definition i have:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:debuggable="true">

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AndroidStartActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".myActivity" />
</application>
```

and of course I have a myActivity.java file....

---

I checked and rechecked the code and all the answers in the web connected to this topic... 
I have the latest version of Android SDK...

So just to know: is this a bug of the sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the exception trace will be helpful to get the cause of exception. 
For eg testClass might not have instantiated as expected.say due to typo error - you might be expecting `com.test.design.{testName}` but getting `com.test.design{testName}` . Notice the `.` in the fully qualified class name

Comment: I have a try catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){   ex.printStackTrace();} after the try, but it doesn't enter there... it simply gives error on screen... and using breakpoint, it arrives till the startActivity(intent)...

Comment: I also put the dot . at the end of "com.test.design" -> "com.test.design." + ...  but it didn't change the result....